# System.Windows.Forms.TextBox does not change ref text

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, inputbox

I have the following code as a popup dialog that takes input from inputBox. I pass in strings as reference hoping the ref string would change on dialog close, so I can get user input. But the strings passed in did not change on dialog close. What did I do wrong?

```
public static DialogResult ShowInputDialog(ref string input1, ref string input2)
{
    var size = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 180);
    var inputBox = new Form { ClientSize = size };

    var panel = new TableLayoutPanel
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(460, 180),
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 15),
        ColumnCount = 2,
        RowCount = 3
    };

    // Add ColumnStyles/RowStyles here

    panel.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Input 1", TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight }, 0, 0);
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Input2", TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight }, 0, 1);
    panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = input1, Width = 280 }, 1, 0);
    panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = input2, Width = 280 }, 1, 1);
    var okButton = new Button{ DialogResult = DialogResult.OK};
    var cancelButton = new Button {DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel};

    var buttons = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    buttons.Controls.Add(okButton);
    buttons.Controls.Add(cancelButton);
    panel.Controls.Add(buttons, 1, 3);
    inputBox.Controls.Add(panel);

    inputBox.AcceptButton = okButton;
    inputBox.CancelButton = cancelButton;

    var result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
    return result;
}
```

The usage of the above code is:

```
string input1 = string.Empty; 
string input2 = string.Empty;
ShowInputDialog(ref input, ref input2);
```

Comment: Your life would be so much simpler if you used the designer to create your form and then setup some properties to retrieve your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `TableLayoutPanel` but maybe you could do something as simple as:

```
 if (inputBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
    input1 = (panel.GetControlFromPosition(1, 0) as TextBox).Text;
    input2 = (panel.GetControlFromPosition(1, 1) as TextBox).Text;
    return DialogResult.OK;
 }

 return DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Your problem at the moment is that you're not actually setting the value anywhere after the dialog is closed.

However, I agree with the comment. A type of MVVM pattern would probably make the maintaining (and creation) of these types of properties and their respective values much easier.

Answer (score 1):

After the user has click ok button, you have to assign the textbox.text value back to input1 and input2